# What to use as key when rendering a list of elements in React if the objects have no property which can be used as an unique identifier?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say I'm building a to do list and I built the `toDos` like this:

```
    const toDo = {
        title: title,
        finished: false,
    }
```

before pushing them to the array that contains all toDos. Once I want to map over them and return JSX, I need to supply them with a unique key, but in this case, I don't have a key on the object, so what do I need to supply in this case?

```
const mappedToDoList = toDoList?.map((element) => {
    return (
        <div className='to-do' key={???}>
            <p>{element.title}</p>
        </div>
    )
})
```

I can't use the index because it causes problems as soon as I start adding/removing `toDos`.

Comment: Why not add a unique `id` key to your todo object when you create it?

Comment: Add a unique while you are creating each todo, 
or loop the todos only first time and add key to it before rendering

Comment: ID's can easily be created via `crypto.randomUUID()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have two options here:

1. the suggested way is to generate a unique key when adding a new `todo` like this:

```
const toDo = {
  id: new Date().getTime(), //a better way might be to use a uuid library to generate this
  title: title,
  finished: false,
};
```

2. is to use `index` + `title` as key just to make react happy, like this:

```
const mappedToDoList = toDoList?.map((element, index) => {
    return (
        <div className='to-do' key={element.title + index}>
            <p>{element.title}</p>
        </div>
    )
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use uuid library

```
npm install uuid
```

Then you can add a unique id for your item

```js
  
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
 const toDo = {
        id: uuidv4(),
        title: title,
        finished: false,
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can map over the list like this:

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

const listItems = numbers.map((number) =>
  <li>{number}</li>
 );
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).